# Run files hidden

Tags: vbscript

I am making a project of batch, and I used this vbscript to run it hidden: but I don't know if it's correct.

```
echo Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Desktop\BatMan.bat" & chr(34), 0
echo Set WshShell = Nothing
echo WScript.Sleep 7500
do
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Downloads\BatManSetup1.bat" & chr(34), 0
echo Set WshShell = Nothing
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Downloads\BatManSetup4.bat" & chr(34), 0
echo Set WshShell = Nothing
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Downloads\BatManSetup5.bat" & chr(34), 0
echo Set WshShell = Nothing
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Downloads\BatManSetup6.bat" & chr(34), 0
echo Set WshShell = Nothing
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Downloads\BatManMain.bat" & chr(34), 0
echo Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Do I actually need to type the echo Set WshShell = Nothing multiple times? And is it possible to run many files hidden in one vbs like that? Will it lag the speed?

Comment: Frankly, I'm a bit surprised your script doesn't CRASH the first time you call `WshShell.Run` after DELETING the object (`Set WshShell = Nothing`).  You should delete the object only ONCE, after you're DONE with it.

Comment: There is probably no need to "delete" it anyway. Once it goes out of scope it should be cleaned up by the garbage collector automatically. I do find it a bit scary that you are executing code without knowing what it does.

Comment: You're also missing the end of the `Do` loop.

Comment: You should add also the tag `batch` and if you want to generate a vbscript from a batch file, you should escape special Characters like `&` and  `)` Take a look at this [Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)